# Can I call a Javascript Function based on contructor position?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to combine the functions `CorrectAppleNo`, `WrongAppleNo1`, `WrongAppleNo2`, and `WrongAppleNo3` below into one function so that based on the constructor position it can return the appropriate values? Or is there a better way to do this?

Like say if I'm calling the function from Answer1 position within the constructor it returns the correct answer, if i am calling the same function from Answer2 of the constructor returns the wrong answer.

I am asking this because if say there are 20 problems with unique solutions typing these functions as return correct return wrong separately is going to be a big headache. I am still a bit new to javascript so apologies if the question is basic!

```js
var paper = [];
paper[0] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);
paper[1] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);
paper[2] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);
paper[3] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);
paper[4] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);
paper[5] = new NewQues(`If Person has a total of 1000 Apples. And he gives ${AppleNo()} to Bill. How many apples does he have remaining`, `${CorrectAppleNo()}`, `${WrongAppleNo1()}`, `${WrongAppleNo2()}`, `${WrongAppleNo3()}`);

function AppleNo() {
  var Apples = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400);
  SendApples = Apples;
  return Apples;
}

function CorrectAppleNo() {
  var Temporary = SendApples;
  var Correct = 1000 - Temporary;
  return Correct;
}

function WrongAppleNo1() {
  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var Temporary = SendApples;
  var Wrong = 1000 - Temporary - somenumber;
  return Wrong;
}

function WrongAppleNo2() {
  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var Temporary = SendApples;
  var Wrong = 1000 - Temporary + somenumber;
  return Wrong;
}

function WrongAppleNo3() {
  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
  var Temporary = SendApples;
  var Wrong = 1000 - Temporary - somenumber;
  return Wrong;
}

// Functions Regarding Questions Above , Code Below

function NewQues(Ques, Answer1, Answer2, Answer3, Answer4) {
  this.Ques = Ques;
  this.Answer1 = Answer1;
  this.Answer2 = Answer2;
  this.Answer3 = Answer3;
  this.Answer4 = Answer4;
};

function Change() {
  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * paper.length);

  SomeQues = paper[somenumber];

  answers = [SomeQues.Ques, SomeQues.Answer1, SomeQues.Answer2, SomeQues.Answer3, SomeQues.Answer4];

  document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = answers[0];
  document.getElementById("question").value = answers[0];

  document.getElementById("answer1").innerHTML = answers[1];
  document.getElementById("answer1").value = answers[1];

  document.getElementById("answer2").innerHTML = answers[2];
  document.getElementById("answer2").value = answers[2];

  document.getElementById("answer3").innerHTML = answers[3];
  document.getElementById("answer3").value = answers[3];

  document.getElementById("answer4").innerHTML = answers[4];
  document.getElementById("answer4").value = answers[4];
}
```

```html
<p id="question"> Question </p>
<p id="answer1"> Answer1 </p>
<p id="answer2"> Answer2 </p>
<p id="answer3"> Answer3 </p>
<p id="answer4"> Answer4 </p>

<button onclick="Change()"> Change Question </button>
```

Comment: @T.J. Crowder Thanks for the edit sir. I shall keep my questions concise in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't understand the question, but I think I do now looking at your answer.

Some suggestions / observations:

- If the result is the same whether `x` is `1`, `2`, or `3`, don't repeat the code, use an `||` ("or') operation.
- The code should handle the case where `x` isn't `0`, `1`, `2`, or `3`, even if you always expect it to be (if you always expect it to be, you can handle it with an error).
- The very, very standard convention in JavaScript is that variables and non-constructor functions start with a lowercase letter. You can use any convention you like in your own code, of course, but if working with others (for instance, asking a question or providing an answer on Stack Overflow), following conventions makes it easier for people to understand your code.
- In modern JavaScript, don't use `var`. Use `const` or `let`.
- Consistency with naming is important. If you use `camelCase` (or, non-standardly, `UpperCamelCase`), use it consistently. Don't have `SendApples` and `somenumber`, for instance. Following convention, they'd be `sendApples` and `someNumber`.
- Don't hide the first statement on a block by putting it on the same line as the opening `{` of the block. It's hard to read, and hard to maintain (what if you need to add a statement before it?).
- Don't hide the end of a block by putting it at the end of the last statement in the block. Again, it's hard to read, and also hard to maintain (what if you need to add a statement after it?).

Granted, those last two are a bit subjective, but while there are several common styles for where `{` and `}` go, **none** of them hides them like that. (I've only seen this fairly recently — I hope some influential teacher isn't teaching this.)

With all that in mind:

```
function correctAppleNo(x) {
    if (x === 0) {
        const right = 1000 - sendApples;
        return right;
    }

    if (x === 1 || x === 2 || x === 3) {
        const someNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
        const wrong = 1000 - sendApples - someNumber;
        return wrong;
    }

    throw new Error(`'x' is expected to be 0, 1, 2, or 3, but got the value ${x}`);
}
```

Comment: .Thats Good advice sir! Thank you so much! 
My question was if it is possible to return such values based on the contructor position, meaning say something like , (if function called from this.Answer1 return right, if called from this.Answer2, return wrong). 
So I can skip putting correctAppleNo(0), correctAppleNo(1) and just put correctAppleNo() . So I can complete it easily like paper[0]=`Question`,`correctAppleNo()`,`correctAppleNo()`,`correctAppleNo()`,`correctAppleNo()` and javascript understands that when I am calling it from this.Answer1 I would want it to return the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

Its a Straightforward answer I should have tried Earlier, using Arguments.

```
function CorrectAppleNo(x) {

if ( x == 0 ) {
    var Correct = 1000 - SendApples ;
    return Correct ;}   

if ( x == 1 ) {var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    var Wrong = 1000 - SendApples - somenumber ;
    return Wrong ;}

if ( x == 2) {  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    var Wrong = 1000 - SendApples - somenumber ;
    return Wrong ;} 

if ( x == 3) {  var somenumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20);
    var Wrong = 1000 - SendApples + somenumber ;
    return Wrong ;}     
    
}
```